# Javafx: How to print string of array in label using button and textfield?

Tags: javafx

I am using an IntelliJIdea. I want to display all the numbers that I submitted in Textfield. So I created an ArrayList to put all the numbers I submitted there. However, every time I pressed the button, it does not add all the list, instead only the 1 number I submitted. How can I show all the numbers that I've submitted in Textfield and display it using label. I am using a separate fxml.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5pyQ.jpg)

sample.fxml:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<GridPane fx:controller="com.binarySearch.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="TOP_LEFT" hgap="10" vgap="10">

    <Label text="Please enter number" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
    <TextField  fx:id="inputNumber" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0" />
    <Button text="Submit" fx:id="submit" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="0" onAction="#handleSubmitPress"/>
    <Button text="Search" fx:id="search" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnIndex="0" onAction="#handleSearchPress" />
    <Label text="You input: " GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.columnIndex="0" />
    <VBox GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.columnIndex="0" >
        <Label fx:id="display" />
    </VBox>

</GridPane>
```

Controller.java

```
package com.binarySearch;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private TextField inputNumber;

    @FXML
    private Button submit;

    @FXML
    private Button search;

    @FXML
    private Label display;

    public void handleSubmitPress() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int num = Integer.parseInt(inputNumber.getText());
        list.add(num);

        for(int x=0; x<list.size();x++) {
            display.setText(list.get(x).toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new list in the method itself. This list is initially empty, so after adding the text, it contains a single element. Furthermore using `setText` replaces the text of the label. It doesn't assign a combination of the strings passed as text; it doesn't add more `Label`s either.

The first issue could be fixed declaring the list as a field, but the second issue is probably solved best by just adding a new `Label` to the `VBox` which may make keeping track of the data in a list unnecessary:

```
private final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
@FXML
private VBox vbox;

public void handleSubmitPress() {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(inputNumber.getText());
    list.add(num);

    vbox.getChildren().add(new Label(Integer.toString(num)));
}
```

```xml
    <VBox GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.columnIndex="0" fx:id="vbox" />
```

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you very much! I appreciate your help. It's because I am having a hard time getting all the attributes or properties of all the fxml components. Seems like I couldn't find the proper documentation of fxml but rather look at this site https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm but that's confusing though

Comment: @user11880836 fxml basically corresponds to calls to certain setters/constructors or adding children to list properties. A tutorial about JavaFX layouts in java may be helpful. This is at least partially documented here: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html (Iirc you constructors with parameters (see `@NamedArg`) and default properties (`@DefaultProperty`) are not explained.) Unless you're using SceneBuilder, it's best to know how to construct scene the in java first...